# Let's float an island on an astrophysical jet

Tags: internal-consistency, astronomy

An [astrophysical jet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysical_jet#Relativistic_jet) is a stream of particles emitted by matter falling into an supermassive star/black hole, travelling at up to 80% the speed of light.

A troll with a portal gun (which places portals instantly) wants to have his house floating above the ground (with his garden) just by using a small part of a jet.

Is this possible? (Probably not)
What issue would come up? Which other unreal technologies would be needed to solve the issues and make this possible?

Comment: Composition of jets is not really known now, there is debate between electron-positron option and electron-nuclei option (and mix of both). Are we to assume one or the other?

Comment: @Mołot yes, just assume what you believe, or assume and handle all three (if it's not too much effort)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A big old beam that might be made up of equal amounts of electrons and positrons? Sounds like a job for Ludicrous Magnets inc.!

This answer makes a series of assumptions:

1: The beam is composed of electrons and positrons in equal proportions with no stray nuclei in there. This is Important.

2: You have some whopping great electromagnets and sturdy enough foundations/structures to mount them on.

3: You have a lot of vertical space to play with.

4: You’re in a vacuum. Seriously: who thinks firing a beam of relativistically fast matter into an atmosphere is sane??

5: Your control systems are insane.

So. If you have those 5 things you can begin.

First you have to build a magnetic field generator such that the portal fires the stream up through practically parallel field lines. As it does so the beam will diverge, as positrons and electrons are deflected exactly oppositely in a magnetic field. This magnetic field generator must be mounted to the main island in such a way that it does not intersect any part of the beam, or Fiery Death will ensue.

Second, way above the first magnetic array (exactly how high depends on how strong your magnets are and how powerful your jet is) you have your island. Attached to the island are two ‘intake ports’. One accepts a positron beam, the other an electron beam. If you position things right then the jets will seperate neatly into two beams that shoot directly into these ports. If you don’t then Fiery Death will ensue.

Thirdly: you have a series of very long, very complicated curves lined with electromagnets. As you have a beam of known magnetic properties and (hopefully) known velocity/energy you should be able to curve these beams round in some (admittedly huge) part circles, emitting beams at various locations in order to keep your island balanced and in place. If your control software isn’t capable of separating the beams appropriately Fiery Death will ensue.

Now, at this point you might be thinking ‘huh, that sounds an awful lot like CERN’. You would be correct. The size of the curves may well be obscene (unless you have some *truly* ludicrous magnets), but it is possible to bend the beams. In so doing you transfer momentum from the beams to the station.

If you can bend the beams around enough (and your station isn’t too heavy, which is again a big assumption) then you can hypothetically balance the force of gravity against the upward pressure of the beams, letting you balance your hermetically sealed house/garden atop the monstrous beam-deflecting complex you have created. If your station is too heavy then... you get the drift.

Now: there are a number of ways this can fail *spectacularly*

1: Control software failure. Your station drifts out of alignment and is bisected by the jet. Fiery Death.

2: Unexpected velocities of particles. Given the weird nature of these phenomena I’m imagining all the particles involved are moving at a set of velocities you know. If they don’t then parts of the beam will hit elsewhere on your station. Fiery Death.

3: Unexpected particle ratios. Much like above, but with an unexpected ratio of positrons to electrons. Fiery Death.

4: Unexpected nuclei. Your magnets, if calibrated for an electron stream, will not handle nuclei. They will impact your station like a stream of baseballs thrown by an angry god. Fiery Death.

5: Power Problems: I dread to think what kind of power requirements this will have. I’d say astronomical, but the pun might kill me. Anyway: any fluctuation in power supply: Fiery Death.

6: Anything else intersecting any of your beams. This includes the floor. The stream of plasma will interact Very Badly with matter, releasing bursts of awful radiation and debris that will hit your station. FIERY. DEATH.

7: Structural Failure. The forces you’ll be dealing with are ungodly. Any weakness in the structure will result in your magnets (and the beam of plasma. Don’t forget the beam of plasma) crushing your station. Crunchy, Fiery Death.

8: ADDENDUM DEATH: Overheating. You’d better have superconductors available, because any inefficient in power delivery or magnetic field design will translate to a lot of heat. AKA Fiery Death.

Anyway. If you avoid all that then you’ll have a free-floating station. The gravity of your station will slowly but surely move the planet you’re hovering over, potentially destabilising it’s orbit and plunging it into the nearest star.

In conclusion: Don’t do this. Fiery Death will ensue.

Comment: Nice answer. But power would *not* be a problem: You separate electrons and positrons at relativistic speed. You must slow them, lest they tear your precious island apart. You can slow them with a large enough electric field, and when you catch them in metal blocks at the end, you get a nice, cheap, high-voltage power source. You must still handle the gamma rays that are produced by the electron/positron annihilation, though.

Comment: @cmaster: Why slow them? The separation happens a long way below the main station and all the momentum transfer is happening via magnetic field over a nice lesiurely curve. You will need a stinking great power supply for your electromagnets, but if you’re playing with portals near black holes I guess that power generation isn’t that big a deal for you, so there’s no need to risk the gamma.

Comment: @cmaster: Though using an electric field as the momentum trap might let you pull momentum out in a much more compact station, but the fields involved would be *intense*. BTW: you just inspired me to add an extra way for this to go catastrophically wrong. Well done!

Comment: @cmaster and I just now realised what your comment was about. You just solved the power problems. Could quite happily use the electron stream for power and the positron steam for balance to avoid any annihilation unpleasantness, though that does turn your station into a Spinning Beam Of Death Machine (TM).

Comment: Since you just haven't mentioned it. where do all the matter from the jet got after we took their power to oppose gravity. do we just spray them out and cause fiery and infernal death or can we use them for something else, like a electric generator?

Comment: @Jannis: In my answer? Fiery death. Though in the comments cmaster suggested using the electron/positron combo to create a high potential difference you could use to power the station.

Answer (score 3):

A stream of particles traveling at relativistic speed has the inconvenience of generating a shower of gamma rays upon impacting other matter.

The higher the flow of particles, the more intense the gamma shower.

Gamma rays are pretty nasty on life form, trolls included I assume, though there are no scientific studies on the topic. Wearing a gamma ray blocking outfit in the garden is at least inconvenient.

Moreover, gamma rays would ablate the material they impinge upon. This means that the house would be literally eaten away in a rather short time.

Therefore a mandatory technology to make this feasible is a gamma shield that doesn't get significant ablation damage and can block induced radiation from reaching sensitive targets for months to years, which is the usual life expectancy for household equipments.

Comment: @Jannis, most of the gamma rays are generated while the stream hits on the target

Comment: It's pretty sad that you say months is usual life expectancy for household equipments and I can't disagree no matter how much I want to.